# How to assert types in an array of objects with Chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, assert

I have the following context:

```js
const data = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'thenamefoo',
    modified: new Date() // random date
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'namebar',
    modified: new Date() // random date
  },
  ...
];

expect(data)...
```

I want to assert that my data will always be an array that have objects with fixed keys (and types).

For instance, I want something like

```js
expect(data)
.to.be.an('array')
.that.all.have.types.like({
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  modified: Date
});
```

Is it possible? How? Any libs?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should focus on validating the data instead of toying with a clunky assertion DSL. With simple true/false checks, all you need is the humble `assert`:

```js
test('my data is valid', () => {
  data.forEach(({id, name, modified}) => {
    assert(typeof id === 'number', `${id} is not a number`);
    assert(typeof name === 'string', `${name} is not a string`);
    assert(modified instanceof Date, `${modified} is not a date`);
  });
});
```

---

#### Going further

This of course doesn't help much if you need to check other things:

1. The array is not empty
2. Each object has exactly `id`, `name` and `modified` as properties. No less no more
3. `id` is a positive integer
4. `name` is not an empty string
5. ...

For more fined-grained control you should definitely look into [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion of asserting the data instead of the types, but I don't know if its appropriated to my case (asserting variable datasets)